# Lua: Find string between two strings

Tags: lua

```
local code = [[
    print("this is a trap")    
    asd("XDasdsadasdasd")
    print("this is a trap")
]]
print("\n\n\n\n\n")
print(string.match(code, 'asd(.*)'))
```

I made this but the problem is it also returns the print under it. It'll return anything under the asd("XDasdsadasdasd"), but i only want whats inside asd("XDasdsadasdasd") to return that will be "XDasdsadasdasd"

Comment: read https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1   parenthesis define a capture if not escaped with `%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses are magic chars in Lua patterns. You need to escape them. Also, you need to stop at the first closing parenthesis. See the code below:

```
print(string.match(code, 'asd%(.-%)'))
```

If you only want what's inside `asd(...)`, then use

```
print(string.match(code, 'asd%((.-)%)'))
```

Comment: How would it go if there was more than one
`local code = [[
asd("one")
print("bait")
asd("twio")
]]` because I believe it only takes the first

Comment: @Birk, use a loop with `string.gmatch`.

Comment: @lhf Wouldn't it be better to use `%b()`?

Comment: @Spar, possibly, but if the string can contain parentheses, then neither my solution nor yours work.

Comment: @lhf Is there more correct way though? `%(%)` vs `%b()`